# How to modify displacement map parameters in PIXI.js using a VIDEO as a displacement map?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

---

**[UPDATE]:**

It wasn't clearly documented on PIXI.js but I have managed to figure this out; I had to edit the displacementFilter *scale*. See the following:

```
    app.renderer.view.style.transform = 'scale(1.1)';
    displacementSprite.scale.x = 2;
    displacementSprite.scale.y = 2;
    displacementFilter.scale.x = 200;
    displacementFilter.scale.y = 200;
```

I also had to enlarge the scale of the base image to cover up the distortion at the edges due to the higher level of displacement.

I'm still looking for a way to loop the displacement .mp4 though, any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

---

I am trying to code a section of my website where the page background is a static .jpg image which would be displaced by a greyscale video of my silhouette (see example below), but I'm having trouble manipulating the *displacement weight*.

I'm having a lot of trouble finding any kind of resource or tutorial for how to code such a thing though - I've managed to get it working with PIXI.js but it seems like this is very limited as far as manipulating parameters like displacement weight goes (I can only seem to edit the scale of the displacement image).

This as as far as I've gotten in browser

[image]

This is the Touchdesigner (not coded) mockup

[image]

As you can see, the displacement weight in what I've been able to recreate in browser is much weaker than what I've been able to achieve in Touchdesigner.

[Here is a link to the displacement map MP4 I'm using.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zfhpGX-IyoSUOFUwtE49cqCeE6HmPBtF?usp=sharing)

My questions are the following:

1. How can I tweak the displacement weight to increase the filter effect?
2. How can I make this code flexible for different browsers/devices?
3. How can I make the displacement video loop?

   ```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.1.3/pixi.min.js"></script>

   <script>

   var app;
   function initPixi() {
     app = new PIXI.Application({width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight});
     document.body.appendChild(app.view);

     var image = new PIXI.Sprite.from("bliss.jpg");
     image.width = window.innerWidth;
     image.height = window.innerHeight;
     app.stage.addChild(image);




     displacementSprite = new PIXI.Sprite.from("blurred2.mp4");
     displacementFilter = new PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter(displacementSprite);

     app.stage.addChild(displacementSprite);
     app.stage.filters = [displacementFilter];

     app.renderer.view.style.transform = 'scale(1.01)';
     displacementSprite.scale.x = 2;
     displacementSprite.scale.y = 2;

     animate() 
   }


   initPixi();
   ```